# Material's ThemeProvider does not apply for my custom Material components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components, material-design, storybook

I built a custom component library with React v18, storybook v7 and material v5.

I configured storybook with ThemeProvider and it works well.

I export Components and theme object like this from ui-library:

```
import { theme } from "./themes/themes";
import Button from "./components/Button/Button";

export { theme, Button };
```

Button is just a simple Material Button.

And my real app:

```
import {theme, Button} from "my-ui-library";
import {Button as MaterialButton} from '@mui/material';

// some codes...

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Button variant="outlined" label="create" />
  <MaterialButton variant="outlined" label="create">create</MaterialButton>
</ThemeProvider>
```

MaterialButton applies theme well but Button does not apply it.

Comment: When you say, `Button is just a simple Material Button.` is it just a re-export of MUI Button or you're wrapping MUI Button in your own component? If it's the latter, I don't think it'd work unless you use the theme from the provider to style it.